# Lightbox popup in main window from image in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, lightbox

I have an image gallery placed in an iframe (not cross domain) and would like to use Lightbox to show a popupdiv in the main frame. Because right now when the image in the iframe is clicked, the popup div just covers the iframe.

I think it might have something to do with setting target="_top", but that doesn't quite do the trick. Setting the window.top location to my main url just causes the page to go to that url.

Comment: Any special reason you are using an iframe here? (I)Frames have many disadvantages as you see, and hardly any advantages over other "include" and/or "scrolling" solutions especially when you are not including cross-domain content.

Comment: I'm using iframes because that seemed the best way for me to include my pages, but doing some research on includes, I think I'll go with that. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe>` cannot access its parent contents unless the parent frame provides a co-operative Javascript.

Instead of embedding your gallery directly via `<iframe>` you should embed it using a helper Javascript.
Then this helper Javascript would communicate with `<iframe>` Javascript via `postMessage()`
and the helper Javascript would do the required DOM manipulation on top level for opening an overlay `<div>` in the top level frame.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage